# VueJs: Component slot as property

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I've read the documentation and I'm not sure if what I'm trying to achieve is actually doable.
What I'm after is the component's property that contains html tags, which obviously produce invalid html - hence I was wondering if there is a way of passing html into the component and sending it further with emitted event.
The most suitable way would be to have `named slot`, but I don't think I can associate content of a named slot with internal property.

The component I work on is a simple confirmation dialog. The trigger component would wrap two slots - one for label and the other for message I'd like to dispatch with the event to the dialog component.

My trigger component looks like this at the moment:

```
<template>
    <a :class="cssClass" @click="clicked()">
        <slot></slot>
    </a>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            route: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            message: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            cssClass: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            window.EventHandler.listen('confirm-dialog-' + this.id + '-called', () => {
                window.location.reload(true);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            clicked() {
                window.EventHandler.fire('top-confirm', {
                    id: 'confirm-dialog-' + this.id,
                    message: this.message,
                    url: this.route
                });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

and when added to the html:

```
<call-dialog
    route="{{ route('subscriber.destroy', $subscriber->id) }}"
    css-class="alert"
    id="{{ $subscriber->id }}"
    message="Are you sure you wish to remove '{{ $subscriber->email }}'?<br />There is no undo!"
>
   <i class="fa fa-trash"></i> Remove
</call-dialog>
```

As you can see, at the moment I'm passing the message using `message` prop, but this particular one contains `<br />` tag, which produces invalid html.

Any idea how to tackle this?

**NOTE**

I think I've found the way of doing it with named slots:

```
<template>
    <a :class="cssClass" @click.prevent="clicked()">
        <slot name="label"></slot>
    </a>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            id: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            route: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            cssClass: {
                type: String,
                required: false
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            window.EventHandler.listen('confirm-dialog-' + this.id + '-called', () => {
                window.location.reload(true);
            });
        },
        methods: {
            message() {
                 return this.$slots.message[0].context.message;
            },
            clicked() {
                window.EventHandler.fire('top-confirm', {
                    id: 'confirm-dialog-' + this.id,
                    message: this.message(),
                    url: this.route
                });
            }
        }
    };
</script>
```

And now simply passing and additional named slot `slot="message"`

```
<call-dialog
    route="{{ route('subscriber.destroy', $subscriber->id) }}"
    css-class="alert"
    id="{{ $subscriber->id }}"
>
    <span slot="label"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
    <span slot="message">Are you sure you wish to remove '{{ $subscriber->email }}'?<br />There is no undo!</span>
</call-dialog>
```

Comment: You can store it in vuex and send key as property. You need key to find value in store

Answer (score 0):

You should use `v-html` inside of the `call-dialog` component to insert the raw HTML from the message prop into an element.

```
<div v-html="message"></div>
```

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm asking for - I'm not using it - I'm passing it further to another component. The question is how to pass it as a property without it actually being an attribute of a component tag.

Comment: @SebastianSulinski create a computed property which returns the string you need. Then pass this computed property as a value of you `message` like this: `:message="myCreatedString"`

Comment: Sorry - I must've not explained it well - I know how to bind properties etc. The value of it will not be bound to any element - it will be dispatched with the event dispatcher - I need to pass it into the component without using attributes - perhaps named slots, but then how can I fetch content of a slot and associate with the local variable for instance  from within the component.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to do something similar for a custom button component.

```
Vue.prototype.$getSlotText = function( name = 'default' ) {
    const htmlElements = this.$slots[name];
    if(!htmlElements || !htmlElements.length) return '';

    return htmlElements.reduce((fullText, {tag, text}) => {
        return fullText + (tag === 'br' ? '\n' : text || '');
    }, '');
}
```

Essentially, this would access the HTML-Elements on the "default" slot (by default).

- If none found, returns `''` blank string.
- If some found, iterates over each Element, concatenates it's `text` property if found, or `\n` if it's a `<br/>` tag.

Note: The `.reduce(...)` method is used for the iteration / concatenation. Alternatively a `.map(...)` call with a similar arrow-function, followed by a `.join('')` would probably result the same thing.